# How to fetch tens of millions of records fast and feed the fetched data in Elasticsearch using Java

Tags: java, oracle, performance, elasticsearch

I have a requirement where I need to fetch tens of millions of records fast from an Oracle database and turn each record into JSON format to ultimately feed it in Elasticsearch. 
What would be the best way to speed this whole process up from fetching from the database to feeding in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: use logstash, read about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin)

Longer version: You should find yourself a compatible JDBC driver, and then tell logstash where to find your table. The example from above page is for postgresql, but the method is the same:

So straight from that page:

```
create table contacts (
    uid serial,
    email VARCHAR(80) not null,
    first_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO contacts(email, first_name, last_name) VALUES('jim@example.com', 'Jim', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO contacts(email, first_name, last_name) VALUES(null, 'John', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO contacts(email, first_name, last_name) VALUES('carol@example.com', 'Carol', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO contacts(email, first_name, last_name) VALUES('sam@example.com', 'Sam', null);
```

if we want to insert that table, we can do so with this config:

```
# file: simple-out.conf
input {
    jdbc {
        # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar"
        # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT * from contacts"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

and call it like so:

```
logstash-1.5.3/bin/logstash -f simple-out.conf Logstash startup
```

more examples available there

Comment: I was thinking of using Logstash, but it turned out that the tool could not handle nested objects i.e. turning tables(flat structure) into JSON like structure

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Most usages for elasticsearch would be, in my eyes at least, to take a nested structure (e.g. relational database) and turn that into a flat structure (a list of documents represented as JSON parts). But this could just be a language / naming thing. I'd still try and fix it like above, so get your complete result in one line back, and then make it a mapping, if possible. If you have an one-to-many relationwith an unpredictable amount of rows, then you're in bad luck and you'd just need to write some code that creates the docs and calls `_bulk` i guess.

Comment: I understand your point. But how would you get rid of the nested structure from the data sourced from RDB? I believe as long as the data is from RDB, there should be (in most cases) one-to-many relationships between tables

Comment: that's tricky indeed. If its a clear case of "at most x" you could just join x times, but that's a real... unpractical method. If you do need the actual nested structure, there's nothing to it but to code it. But you might want to evaluate what your mapping will be,and how usefull it is? Actual nested fields can complicate things sadly. What I do is select the data in code, serialze to JSON and curl to `_bulk` every 3k documents